# Porting XLL from xlw to xlw.Net

Tags: c#, c++, xll

I have 2 projects developed in VS 2008.

1. C++ dlls (the core library)
2. C++ Excel Add-in Xll (using XLW 4_0_0f0)

I transfer Xlw::XlfOper variables between dlls and xll.
It has been working fine for a long time.

Now I am trying to reimplement the Add-in project in C# using xlw.Net (like below 3 projects),

1. Native C++ dlls (the core library)
2. Managed C++ wrapper dll (C++/CLI)
3. C# Excel Add-in Xll (using XLW.Net)

Because xlw.Net does not support XlfOper, I can use Xlw::CellMatrix in my C++ dlls instead.
I am doing conversion between xlw::CellMatrix and xlwDotNet::CellMatrix in the managed dll.
Then I create a template Add-in project using XLW.Net and reference the wrapper dll.
But it throws CS:0433 : Type 'xlwDotNet::CellMatrix' already exists in both dlls (ie. wrapper and xlw.Net).

May be I can get rid of this error by using compiler command reference alias,
but my question is not only particularly about this error, but the way I am porting Add-in from C++ to C#.
To be specific, are there other better ways to create XLL in C# in my situation?  I am new to .Net.
It would be very simple if my native dlls did not use CellMatrix, or if my core library is written in C#.
Has anybody experienced this kind of situation? I did lot of trial-error and searched internet for this issue, but no success.

The native library is quite big and I don't want to convert it into C# due to performance issue.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the extra .NET wrapper?

Comment: From C#, I pass as argument xlwDotNet::CellMatrix to the .Net wrapper. In the wrapper it will be converted to xlw::CellMatrix and will be passed to native dll. And native dll returns xlw::CellMatrix and I will convert it into xlwDotNet::CellMatrix in the wrapper and return it to C#. You see, xlw is native C++ and xlwDotNet is managed C++, so I had to convert the CellMatrix while transition. If you think extra .Net wrapper is unnecessary, I am eager to hear more.

Comment: I mean, why do you need to involve .NET at all? What were the shortcomings of the native-only add-in? A better alternative for the .NET side is Excel-DNA (http://exceldna.codeplex.com), but it doesn't solve your issue of how to deal with the xlw-specific type you use in your core library.

Comment: Before delivering my library to clients, I want to obfuscate and license it. I heard Crypto obfuscator and Crypto license tools are really good (http://www.ssware.com/). But they work only on .Net products.